# How to hide Login and Register button after login by user?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a school project. I'm able to login user successfully who registered. But when he/she loged-in how can I hide `Login` and `Register` page link. I'm using `css` and `<ul>` for them. And after `sign-out` how can I show them again.
Here is the coding of my links on `MasterPage`

```
<td id="tabs2" style="width:190px">
                <ul id="logreg">
                            <li><a href="Login.aspx" ><span>LogIn</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="Registration.aspx"><span>Register</span></a>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                </td>
```

[image]

And how can I use lable like a button to `SignOut`.

Comment: Are you using forms authentication?

Comment: @curt no I'm not using that. I will check on every page load the vale of Session. If it will null I'll hide the elements by ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the elements in a `placeholder` control, and set the `Visible` attribute depending on session state.

```
    <td id="tabs2" style="width:190px">
                    <ul id="logreg">
                          <asp:placeholder id="NotLoggedInPH" runat="server">
                                <li><a href="Login.aspx" ><span>LogIn</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="Registration.aspx"><span>Register</span></li></a>
                         </asp:placeholder>
                         <asp:placeholder id="LoggedInPH" runat="server" visible="false">
                                <li><asp:HyperLink id="btnLogout" runat="server"><span>Logout</span></asp:HyperLink></li>
                         </asp:placeholder>                                    
                    </ul>
   </td>
```

Then in your `Page_Load`:

```
if (!(session["sessionName"])){
    NotLoggedInPH.visible = false;
    LoggedInPH.visible= true;
}
```

Comment: I think there is no opening tag for `</asp:hyperlink>` and no closing tag for the `<asp:linkbutton>`.

Comment: thnx curt +1, why i cant +10 this answer :(

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to just check `Request.IsAuthenticated`

```
<% if(!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated) { %>
  <ul id="logreg">
    <li><a href="Login.aspx" ><span>LogIn</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="Registration.aspx"><span>Register</span></a></li>
  </ul>
<% } else { %>
   // Show a logout button
<% } %>
```

Comment: Yes it seems good for my design sir. but I'm new to this field and it will be a stupid question for you. Why r %> this sign is used?

Comment: `<%` is how you inline server side code on an .aspx page. The statement contained between `<% %>` is actually C# code.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the `LoginView` control and `Forms Auth`, but here are some ways to get your current code to work:

**Assuming Forms Auth:**

```
<li id="liLogin" runat="server" visible='<%= !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated %>' ><a href="Login.aspx"><span>LogIn</span></a></li>    
<li id="liReg" runat="server" visible='<%= !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated %>' ><a href="Registration.aspx"><span>Register</span></a></li>
<li id="liSignout" runat="server" visible='<%= User.Identity.IsAuthenticated %>' ><a href="Signout.aspx"><span>Signout</span></a></li>
```

**Using Session var:**

```
<li id="liLogin" runat="server" visible='<%= (Session["bla"] == null) %>' ><a href="Login.aspx"><span>LogIn</span></a></li>    
<li id="liReg" runat="server" visible='<%= (Session["bla"] == null) %>' ><a href="Registration.aspx"><span>Register</span></a></li>
<li id="liSignout" runat="server" visible='<%= (Session["bla"] != null) %>' ><a href="Signout.aspx"><span>Signout</span></a></li>
```

Comment: i"m not using Form authentication so will it work in that case. And also I need how to use a lable like a button for SignOut.

Comment: If you are using the Membership Provider model.

Comment: Updated since you added you are using Session

Comment: I'll use and give you a reply. But it seems very helpful. In this case I have not to use the lable for `Signout`. But one question still in my mind how to `Session` value become `null` on `Signout` Link click.

Comment: Sesssion["bla"] = null in the Signout.aspx code-behind then redirect.

Comment: I'm getting this error Error Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= (Session["id"] == null) %>' for the 'Visible' property.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply create a user session and check whether `sign-in` user exist or not if exist show `SignOut` otherwise show `login panel`.

Answer (score 1):

adding runat="server" attribute, though its simple trick.

```
<td id="tabs2" style="width:190px" runat="server"> 
                <ul id="logreg">
                            <li><a href="Login.aspx" ><span>LogIn</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="Registration.aspx"><span>Register</span></a>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                </td>
```

after Login Successfull, you can do like this

```
tabs2.Visible=false
```

Comment: yup :) When you set runat="server", you can achive same functionalities in your server side code, you can add cssclass, attributes, many more things which you can do with normal html tags :)

Comment: Sir it is not working giving error that ID is not present in the context.

Comment: it will work, can you give your complete mark up.  and make sure that you added runat attribute to that <td> cell, and also check typo mistakes. tab2.Visible = false;

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using Forms Authentication and your teacher does not allow you to use LoginView Control, I will give  you an other option... Here is what I will do..

1. I would have kept the common functionality like the header in a master page. This way the 
   user login check would have been centralised.
2. I would have converted the  to asp:hyperlink control. OnLoad method of master page class check if the session variable which holds the id and if it is not null do the following..
   hyperlinkObj.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");

Comment: It's not allowed to us because my teacher needs accomplish it manually.

Comment: Are you using session to maintain if the user is authenticated or any other way?

Comment: Yes exactly I'm using Session["id"] to check the user on PageLoad event.

Comment: Sir can you tell me through some code. If I'm getting you right then you mean to say that I've to change the `<a>` tag with `<asp:hyperlink>`.

Comment: Yes avirk. I would change <a> tag to <asp:hyperlink>

Answer (score 0):

I Just put User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false and it hides the login

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a>
                </li>
            }
            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated  == false )
            {
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Login" asp-action="UserLogin">Login</a>
                </li>
            }
            
        </ul>
```